# Prove direct product of elements of subgroup is a subgroup of direct products of the group

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

> Let $(G_1,*),(G_2,!)$ be 2 groups. Prove that if $H_1$ is a subgroup of $G_1$ and $H_2$ is a subgroup of $G_2$, then $$H_1\times H_2 = \{(g_1,g_2) \in G_1\times G_2 
> \mid g_1 \in H_1, g_2 \in H_2\}$$ is a subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$

I proved the first condition of a subgroup by saying since $e$ exists in both $H_1$ and $H_2$ because they're both subgroups, the direct product of them, which is $\{e_1,e_2\}$ must exist in $G_1 \times G_2$. But then I'm pretty much lost after that...

Comment: Do you know what other properties you have to check in order to show that a subset of a group is a subgroup?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(g_1, g_2), (h_1, h_2)\in H_1\times H_2$. We show that $(g_1, g_2)(h_1, h_2)^{-1}\in H_1\times H_2$ to fulfill the requirements of the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) (as you have already shown that $H_1\times H_2$ is nonempty).

Indeed, we have

$$\begin{align}
(g_1, g_2)(h_1, h_2)^{-1}&=(g_1, g_2)(h_1^{-1}, h_2^{-1})\\
&=(g_1\ast h_1^{-1}, g_2!h_2^{-1})\\
&\in H_1\times H_2,
\end{align}$$

since $H_1\le G_1$ and $H_2\le G_2$.